# Limiting Results in DataGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid

I have a DataGrid set up with a list of projects shown, I have a drop down list with three options, "15" Results, "25" Results and "All". I have a method in the cs OnSelectedIndexChanged that should change the paging setup for the DataGrid, I have checked the value that is passed to the method and it is correct, however, when I run the application and select an option from the drop down list nothing happens.

Does anyone know why this might be happening? Can paging for a DataGrid only be specified on PageLoad?? Or am I just completely approaching this problem the wrong way.....

Thanks in advance for any help!

This is my method in the code behind

```
protected void ddlShowIncomplete_OnSelectedIndexChanged(Object sender,EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ddlShowIncomplete.SelectedValue == "15")
        {
            dgRequests.AllowPaging = true;
            dgRequests.PageSize = 5;
        }
        else if (ddlShowIncomplete.SelectedValue == "25")
        {
            dgRequests.AllowPaging = true;
            dgRequests.PageSize = 2;
        }
        else if (ddlShowIncomplete.SelectedValue == "All")
        {
            dgRequests.AllowPaging = false;
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to rebind the data grid after changing the page size. Add

```
dgRequests.DataSource = GetMyDataSource();
dgRequests.DataBind();
```

at the end of your method.

Comment: @korymiller Don't worry, it happens!! Hope this resolves your issue.

Comment: I also had to re declare the data source as well but yes it did fix the problem!

Comment: Yes, you'll need to do that. Updated answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Try using OnRowCommand event

example:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnPageIndexChanging="NewxPage" OnRowCommand="GridViewUpdate" />

protected void GridViewUpdate(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {


    }
```